# gradle fails when ionic cordova build android on Mac 10.x

Tags: android, macos, cordova, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin

When trying to build an Ionic project `ionic cordova build android` on Mac  v10.x I get this error:

```
Subproject Path: CordovaLib 

Configuration 'compile' in project ':' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
null

The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.

at build_1v81ywijexel39ggzi5morld0.run(<Userspath>/platforms/android/build.gradle:143)
org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23+
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> 

All flavors must now belong to a named flavor dimension. Learn more at https://d.android.com/r/tools/flavorDimensions-missing-error-message.html
```

The error suggests it is a Gradle issue.  Anyone run into this and been able to solve the issue?  What should I do?

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.4.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-12-20 15:45:23 UTC
Revision:     10ed9dc355dc39f6307cc98fbd8cea314bdd381c

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
JVM:          1.8.0_161 (Oracle Corporation 25.161-b12)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.13.2 x86_64
```

Using Ionic `v3.19.x` and Cordova `v7.1.0`, and updating Cordova `v8.0` definitely doesn't resolve the issue, also using cordova-android `v6.2.3`

Comment: I have never worked with ionic but if you have access to your build.gradle. The solution is in the question... All flavors must now belong to a named flavor dimension. Learn more at https://d.android.com/r/tools/flavorDimensions-missing-error-message.html

Comment: build.gradle is automatically generated file

Comment: @ewgen you figure this out?  I'm haveing the exact same issue using the same versions of ionic, cordova, and OS

Comment: what is the cordova-android version? cc @mtpultz

Comment: Hi @SurajRao, I'm using `"cordova-android": "^6.2.3"`

Comment: @ewgen are you using crosswalk plugin?

Comment: Thank you! It works with cordova@8.0.0, cordova-android@6.3.0, cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview@2.4.0 and crosswalk@21.51.546.7 for Android 4.1.2. But also with cordova-android@7.0.0 for Android >=4.4

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your `cordova-android` platform. Looks like the gradle build structure in the older platform is not compatible with android gradle version you are using. Current version seems to be [7.0.0](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/RELEASENOTES.md#700-nov-30-2017).

```
ionic cordova platform add android@latest
```

**EDIT**
 do note that [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/blog/crosswalk-final-release.html) project /plugin is no longer maintained if you plan to downgrade as per the other answer

Comment: Instead of bumping the Android version, which would mean dropping users that don't have Android 7+.  Is there a way to `brew install gradle@4.1` instead?  I tried adding Gradle 4.1 installed via Android Studio to my path, but that doesn't seem to work - `export PATH="/Applications/Android Studio/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin":$PATH`

Comment: gradle 4.1 is the newer version.. Also your app will pick that gradle itself. you can verify this by running `cordova requirements` in your project folder

Comment: also you are bumping `cordova-android` version.. you can check the API you are targetting in the platform folder build.gradle

Comment: @mtpultz the cordova-android version has nothing to do with the versions of Android it supports, cordova-android 7 supports SDK 16 and greater (will be changed to SDK 19 and newer in next update)

Comment: I've updated cordova-android to v7.0 so the app works with Gradle v4.4.1, and add Cocoapods which was apparently also missing according to `cordova requirements`, and seems to have gotten passed this issue, but doesn't complete the build based on another error that doesn't have much in the way of information even when using `--verbose` - https://pastebin.com/97Y2tszu.

Comment: cordova-android 7 is not compatible with crosswalk plugin

Comment: For some reason the original project wouldn't build regardless of the update to `cordova-android 7.0.0`, but I decided to try creating another new project and this one built first time and I saw that `cordova-android 7.0.0` was installed in the output.

Comment: @mtpultz.. it could be because of the crosswalk plugin.. however do note that https://crosswalk-project.org the project /plugin is no longer maintained if you plan to downgrade as per the other answer

Answer (score 0):

cordova-android 7 is not compatible with crosswalk, so you'll have to downgrade to cordova-android 6.4.0.

I don't see it mentioned in the release notes, but was mentioned in the cordova-android 7.0.0 release mail.

Comment: however it is no longer maintained https://crosswalk-project.org/blog/crosswalk-final-release.html.You do need to take that into account

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a very similar error and eventually resolved it running this:
`brew install gradle`
I also had to download version 8 of the java runtime for developers.